# How can I set up Apache Tomcat to prerender a subset of the pages it serves?

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have a set of jsp pages that use jsp, java, and DB queries to calculate their output.  However the information on the pages rarely change (maybe once per build).  While I can certainly set the cache headers correctly I'd like to prerender them as well.

Does anyone konw how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts:

Without more information this looks a lot like preliminary optimization. Unless your server really suffers from this operation, I'd postpone all work on optimizing it to when it becomes. You might do several hours of work and gain 0.05% of execution time. There might be other issues that save you 10% or 50% of execution time. Find those and invest your time there - it's a lot higher ROI. As optimized code is typically not really obvious to maintainers coming after you, rather optimize where it's really relevant.

If you determine that this actually eats away significant performance and is worth optimizing, there are different ways to think about the problem: Just because you're using Tomcat, you don't have to utilize JSPs, but you can also buffer the plain output and deliver it from a (caching) servlet. The Servlet API brings you ServletFilters, which you can use to intercept outputs: Write a Servlet Filter to Buffer the first result and deliver it later, while blocking the JSP in the back

Also, take a look at how JSPs are generated: They actually get transformed (compiled) into a servlet that literally hardcodes a lot of output. If you just use a bean to cache all of the (somewhat) variable output and use it in the JSP - instead of actual DB lookups - there's not much performance penalty at all in using a JSP. You can look at the resulting servlets in tomcat's work directory - get an impression what actually happens in the background, it's quite interesting.

Now that I've written this, my preference for order is:

1. Don't do anything unless you can prove that this any change will be a significant improvement
2. Cache the output in a bean and just use the JSP to print the contents of the bean (the lookup of the bean means: First lookup accesses DB, subsequent lookups return the same object)
3. Servlet Filters. However, I personally don't like the caching on HTML level as general problem solution if it's not for resources like CSS/JS-libraries/images (and for them it's rather HTTP-level).